# Manipulate String to Match Validation Pattern

Tags: jquery, web-services, validation

I have a validation WCF web service that allows me to validate strings, postcodes, emails etc.  It works well, returning a JSON response.  What I'd be keen to do however is:

1. Have the user complete a textbox with their entry;
2. Validate the response with the WCF service;
3. Show a visual cue to the user that validation has either passed or failed;
   (so far I can do all this using Jquery & my WCF service)
4. Change the textbox pattern to match the accepted pattern.  Such as if I entered a telephone number: 01234 567890, it would change, (like on an iphone) to my defined pattern of +44 (0) 1234 567890. I'd like this to happen inline, live, so I know this maybe some form of Jquery work - any ideas?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficult thing isn't implementing this in jquery, but rather finding an algorithm that does your formatting.

You would need to match parts of the input to parts of the desired pattern. Maybe if you started from the back, you could assign numbers to the actual phone number part and include spaces where necessary; then as you come to the front with the missing ( ), you would notice when you reach the 0 that you're missing a closing bracket, so you could insert it. Same for the closing bracket when you read the end of input but expect an opening bracket. . Now you're out of input but you still have the international +44 in your desired pattern, so you just assume the user forgot to add it and add it for him.

For phone numbers, this seems an easy way to go, because when you leave something out, it's always at the beginning (international code or area code).

In more general terms, matching subexpressions of the desired format in the actual input will work as long as the actual input has only one interpretation (if a character of input could be a part of either one subexpression or the other, then you'll have to explain to the user why your algorithm sometimes does the "wrong" thing when expanding his input to your desired format.

Matching subexpressions can be done with regular expressions in javascript, so you don't have to write your own expression matcher. Use subexpression grouping and then concatenate the matched groups together using string concatenation, inserting formatting characters between the matched groups as needed.

Here's a small example of what I mean:

```
function format_phonenumber(unformatted) {
  var regex = /(\d{3})(\s*-?\s*)(\d{3})\s*(\d{4})/gi;
  var m = regex.exec(unformatted)
  return m[1] + "-" + m[3] + " " + m[4]; 
}

/* unformatted junk */
var junk = "5551234567";
alert("Formatted: " + format_phonenumber(junk));
```

You can change junk to "555      1234567" or 555- 1234567" etc, and the match groups will still match the right subexpressions and produce a nicely formatted output "555-123 4567" (I don't know how you format your phone numbers, but you get the idea). But everything depends on how clever your subexpression matching is. Of course, the formatter described above should have a failsafe, so that if the regex doesn't match, you end up with the original, unformatted string instead of an actual piece of junk.

Now if you give your input box in question an id, you can attach an event listener to it which will read out the data in the input box, run it through your formatter and store it back into the text field with jquery like so:

```
var unformatted = $("#myinputbox").val();
var formatted = format_phonenumber(unformatted);
$("#myinputbox").val(formatted);
```

Comment: +1 a fine answer JeSuisse.  Well written and lots of points to think about. THanks for the example code also, its just the sort of ideas/possibilities I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for jQuery might be worth a look.